# How to create interface in java

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am new at using graphic interface for java.
I need to do a layout for my program in java to look something like this
http://i1184.photobucket.com/albums/z321/Rbn_Veiga/Picture111.jpg

Comment: Have you heard of Java Swing? if not see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: Hi Rbn, you need to specify more information for your question to be answered. What type of application is it? Web based or desktop? You're probably going to need a UI framework of some sort so if you haven't already looked at them that's probably a good idea.

Comment: yes i had the problem is that i can use the button and the choise but i can organise in the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) will fit. You can see tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Answer (score 0):

that about lots of [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) (with [LineBorder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)), and [JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) are layed with different [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)